# Unity3d- как масштабировать фигуры, чтобы при старте игры между созданными фигурами были зазоры(растояния)?

Tags: unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это карта из плоских геометрических фигур(в основном это треугольники).Чтобы процесс был быстрым, я решил создавать каждую новую фигуру от вершин предыдущих, или, если создавал фигуру в произвольных точках,то использовал прилипание для того, чтобы сделать целостную карту. Но вот проблема, мне нужно, чтобы между треугольниками было небольшое расстояние. Пробовал при старте уменьшать localScale- не помогло, вся карта уменьшается, но зазоры не появляются.

Comment: А ты Localscale меняешь у всей карты сразу? или отдельно у каждой геометрической фигуры?(треугольника)

Comment: У каждой фигуры, тем не менее, уменьшается вся карта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашёл плагин в Unity Store который создаёт двухмерные геометрические фигуры.